# Business Days between two dates

Tags: date-and-time

I can easily add business days to a given date,

```
future = DatePlus[Today, {9, "BusinessDay"}]
```

Is there some way to measure the business days between two dates? In other words, a version of

```
DateDifference[Today, future]
```

that returns `9 BusinessDays` instead of `13 days`?

Comment: Try `DayCount[Today, future, "BusinessDay"]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DayCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayCount):

```
?DayCount
```

> DayCount[Subscript[date, 1],Subscript[date, 2]] gives the number of days from Subscript[date, 1] to Subscript[date, 2].
>   DayCount[Subscript[date, 1],Subscript[date, 2],daytype] gives the number of days of the specified daytype from Subscript[date, 1] to Subscript[date, 2]. >>

For your example:

```
future = DatePlus[Today, {9, "BusinessDay"}];

DayCount[Today, future, "BusinessDay"]
```

> 9